# What are the two params in the function and how does this work?

Tags: jquery

I saw this in an application and it works well but i dont understand how it works.... What is the function(i,text) part doing and what are they for

its being used [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tDr4R/1/)

```
$(this).text(function(i,text) { return (text == 'Show') ? 'Hide' : 'Show'; });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain jQuery methods let you pass a function in that manner. When you do, it iterates over the elements in the jQuery object.

In this case:

- `i` is the index of the current item in the set
- `text` is the current text content value (before you modify it)

That is the pattern for most of the functions that have this capability.

Think of it like this:

```
$(this).each(function( i ) {
    var i = i; // Redundant, I know.
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text( (text == 'Show') ? 'Hide' : 'Show' );
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

I guess I should note that in your particular example, since there's only one element, it appears to be being used to prevent the need to explicitly call `text()` twice in the handler, like this:

```
var $th = $(this);
$th.text(($th.text() == 'Show') ? 'Hide' : 'Show' );
```

I'm not sure which would perform better.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the jQuery API:
http://api.jquery.com/text/

the function is passed an index (`i`) and the text (`text`).

`text()` would return the jQuery objects text value.

As a function is passed as a parameter that functions return value will be set as the jQuery objects text value.

So, the anonymous function is called with the current text value, checked if it is `'Show'`, and then set accordingly (by function return which is then passed to the `text()`-fn).